# Display blinking with OpenGL on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I'm currently developing a simple OpenGl app with C++ using GLFW3 and GLAD generator. When I run the program, my whole display is blinking black. How can I fix this?

```
#include "include/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT,           "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

// glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
// ---------------------------------------
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

// render loop
// -----------
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // input
    // -----
    processInput(window);

    // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

// glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are     pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Here is my glxinfo | grep OpenGl

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I suppose that the problem is related to the fact that OpenGL settings affect not only on my project, but the whole system. So I'm wondering, is this a problem in my code or it is a problem with my hardware- and only a system upgrade can solve this awful blinking.

Comment: You are not drawing anything, so you'll see whatever is stored in the (uninitialized) backbuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks drawing command(s). You should add drawing command(s) into your rendering loop after processing input but before swapping buffers.

e.g To fill background with a color blue

```
    ...
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, it is working now. But I`m still wondering, why it was blinking?

Comment: `glfwSwapBuffers()` swaps the FRONT and BACK buffer. The former is for display on screen, the second to render into (by OpenGL commands). If you clear only once, one buffer is filled with "clear color" the other is in its initial state (in this case filled with 0s which make it black). Due to the repeated `glfwSwapBuffers()`, they become visible alternately, (and the answer tells how to fix this).

Comment: Actually, a modern GL implementation might use a more than 2 buffers, in any order, and might also reallocate new ones at any time. From the GL side, the contents of the back buffer explicitely are _undefined_ after a buffer swap operation, so _everything_ might appear when you swap without drawing (getting zero or parts of previous frames is most common, though).

Comment: agree to @derhass. When you don't clear the buffer it will draw what it has in its current buffer which will most likely produce a glitched/corrupted view.